# Assembly code error

Tags: assembly

I came across this assembly code and when trying to compile it it said there was an error. Not know much about assembly i was wondering if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

```
JMP 0x1F
POPL %ESI
MOVL %ESI, 0x8(%ESI)
XORL %EAX, %EAX
```

Comment: What was the error and what assembler/architecture are you using?  Also, I recommend reformatting your code so it's more clear as everything is on one line here.

Comment: The complete code can be found in http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=49&id=14.

Comment: I formatted it originally but forgot to mark it as "code" in the post

Comment: What assembler are you using? This is AT&T-syntax you should try the `gas`-assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a label at the destination of the `JMP` and use that instead of the constant `0x1F`. Alternatively, knowing the length of the instruction, use a construct such as `JMP .+length+offset`, in this case length is 2 bytes, so it becomes `JMP .+0x21`. This will be then encoded as `0xeb 0x1f` which is what the phrack link apparently wants. Relative jumps in x86 are encoded as offsets from the start of the next instruction, if you don't know the instruction length you can put a label after the instruction like so:

```
JMP next+0x1f
next:
POPL %ESI
MOVL %ESI, 0x8(%ESI)
XORL %EAX, %EAX
```

(Local labels may be helpful, but in this particular case `1f+0x1f` would have been very confusing.)

Be advised, when assembling code the assembler might pick an encoding you don't expect and hence mess up your offsets if you don't use labels.